# size of type vs its unsigned equivalent?

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed

The standard specifies minimum ranges that can be hold by arithmetic integer type. However, is there a guaranty that for each signed integer, its unsigned equivalent has the same size?

In other words, is it Always true that:

```
sizeof(short) == sizeof(unsigned short)
sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int)
sizeof(long) == sizeof(unsigned long)
sizeof(long long) == sizeof(unsigned long long)
```

?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just did not find this question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*(All ISO Standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/))*</sub>

---

> However, is there a guaranty that for each signed integer, its unsigned equivalent has the same size?

Yes.

From [[basic.fundamental]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#3) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> #### [basic.fundamental]/3
>
> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a
>   corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type:
>   “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”,
>   “`unsigned long int`”, and “`unsigned long long int`”, **each of which
>   occupies the same amount of storage and has the same alignment
>   requirements as the corresponding signed integer type**; [...]